# Google Nearby is no longer showing nearby notifications

Tags: google-nearby

Google Play Services/Nearby is no longer showing any nearby notifications, I can see them in the nearby app on my 
Android smartphone, but not in the notification drop-down bar.

I have not muted anything, my google play services notifications are on and I have allowed notifications in the nearby app.

Is anyone experiencing the same thing?
If so, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, turns out having too many beacons in one project on google beacon dashboard is not a good idea.

Who would have known, always learning with these things!

Comment: I'm having an issue with this too. Do you know how many you had in your dashboard when it stopped working?

If this is the case then how do some people have fleets with thousands of beacons?

Comment: Okay so it seems to be a combination of too many beacons and the content that is on those beacons I think. I&#39;m not too sure exactly. I've had Facebook website link which did this, then changing it to an app intent solved the problem.